# Concatenating Broken Strings Across Lists - Python

Tags: python, string, list

I just beginning to program in Python. I have read in some records from a text file into lists where the fourth item in the record is a long string which sometimes spans multiple lines. For example,

```
[ *, *, *, TXT1]
[TXT2]
[TXT3]
[ *, *, *, TXT4]
[TXT5]
[ *, *, *, TXT6]
[ *, *, *, TXT7]
```

How can I create a new list of lists from the original such that it correctly shows

```
[ *, *, *, TXT1+TXT2+TXT3]
[ *, *, *, TXT4+TXT5]
[ *, *, *, TXT6]
[ *, *, *, TXT7]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Parse CSV Correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296585/python-parse-csv-correctly)

Comment: Can you show your existing code?

Comment: If you're trying to parse CSV data, the `csv` module should always be the first place you look. Only if you can't describe the quirks of your format in a way that makes that module happy should you bother write your own parser.

Comment: Also, does your data really look like this, with each line in brackets, and a space before each element, including the first, except on a continuation line? If so, that's not too hard to parse. But it's an odd format, and you haven't given us any *real* sample data, so I'm not going to go off and write code for something that may not be what you actually need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of lists here called `linelist` that looks like `[[*,*,*,TXT1],[TXT2],[TXT3],[*,*,*,TXT4],...]`:

```
newoutput = []
for item in linelist:
   if len(item) == 1:
       newoutput[-1][-1] += item[0]
   else:
       newoutput.append(item)
```

At the end, your output will be like:

```
[
    [*,*,*,TXT1+TXT2+TXT3],
    ...
]
```

In use:

```
>>> a
[['.', '.', '.', 'a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['.', '.', '.', 'd'], ['.', '.', '.', 'e']]

>>> newoutput = []
>>> for item in a:
...   if len(item) == 1:
...     newoutput[-1][-1] += item[0]
...   else:
...     newoutput.append(item)
...
>>> newoutput
[['.', '.', '.', 'abc'], ['.', '.', '.', 'd'], ['.', '.', '.', 'e']]
>>>
```