# Read text file and write file from specific contents

Tags: python, parsing

I'd like to create and write new file from text file.
The challenge I've faced is how to get the contents of specific columns.

The input file is messed-up.

For example,

`input.txt` (tab-delimited: the total number of columns differs across rows)

```
CATEGORY      NEIGHBOUR        NUMBER1   NUMBER2     TOTAL
city          Washington    30        50          80
county        mountain      in        seattle     10        4         30
community     church        men       15          5         4
```

`output.txt` (What I'd like to create. 3 columns per row )

```
CATEGORY                      NUMBER1      TOTAL    
city Washington               30           80
county mountain in seattle    10           30 
community church men          15           4
```

What should I do to write like this?

Comment: While well defined, you haven't really shown us what you've tried so far?  Can you do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Parse CSV Correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296585/python-parse-csv-correctly)

Comment: Do you really care about the left-justification of the columns, or will tab-delimited output suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this python script:

```
file_in  = open('input.txt', 'r')
file_out = open('output.txt', 'w')

for line in file_in:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.split('\t')

    CATEGORY = ' '.join(line[:-3]) ##set variable as beginning of line 
                                   ##to before 3rd last column
    NUMBER_1 = line[-3] ##set variable as 3rd last column
    TOTAL = line[-1]    ##set variable as last column

    file_out.write('%s\t%s\t%s\n' % (CATEGORY, NUMBER_1, TOTAL))

file_in.close()
file_out.close()
```

- run script by: `python <ABOVE_SCRIPT>.py` (assumes **input.txt** is in the same directory as the script)
- The output will return "NEIGHBOUR" in the header line of **output.txt** ... you can always erase that

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
lines = open('in_file', 'r').readlines()
for line in lines:
    fields = line.split('\t')
    ...
```