# Parse CSV file and modify columns

Tags: python, csv

I'd like to change a CSV file in a specific way. This is my sample CSV file:

```
name,time,Operations
Cassandra,2015-10-06T15:07:22.333662984Z,INSERT
Cassandra,2015-10-06T15:07:24.334536781Z,INSERT
Cassandra,2015-10-06T15:07:27.339662984Z,READ
Cassandra,2015-10-06T15:07:28.344493608Z,READ
Cassandra,2015-10-06T15:07:28.345221189Z,READ
Cassandra,2015-10-06T15:07:29.345623750Z,READ
Cassandra,2015-10-06T15:07:31.352725607Z,UPDATE
Cassandra,2015-10-06T15:07:33.360272493Z,UPDATE
Cassandra,2015-10-06T15:07:38.366408708Z,UPDATE
```

I know how to read from CSV file using python parser but I'm totally a beginner with that. I need to get such an output:

```
start_time,end_time,operation
2015-10-06T15:07:22.333662984Z,2015-10-06T15:07:24.334536781Z,INSERT    
2015-10-06T15:07:27.339662984Z,2015-10-06T15:07:29.345623750Z,READ
2015-10-06T15:07:31.352725607Z,2015-10-06T15:07:38.366408708Z,UPDATE
```

**Comment:**
The start time is a timestamp given at beginning of specific query (insert/read,update) and accordingly the end time is completion of the query.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296585/python-parse-csv-correctly) and to the python documentation:

[datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

Comment: I just read about python parser for csv. I'm totally newbie with python that I could only read from my csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears from your sample that you can (presumably) guarantee that the first entry of a certain kind in the Operations column, and the last entry of that same kind are the start and stop times. If you can't guarantee this, then it's slightly more complicated, but let's *assume you can't* – to be more robust.

One thing we *can* assume is that the data represented in the CSV is the entirety. If you're missing entries for a particular operation, there's little we can do. We also want to read the timestamps, which we can do using the `dateutil.parser` module.

So we can start by setting up a short dictionary for keeping track of our values, and a function for populating the dictionary, which accepts one line at a time.

```py
import dateutil.parser

ops = dict()

def update_ops(opsdict, row):

    # first get the timestamp and op name in a useable format
    timestamp = dateutil.parser.parse(row[1])
    op_name = row[2]

    ## now populate, or update the dictionary
    if op_name not in opsdict:
        # sets a new dict entry with the operation's timestamp.
        # since we don't know what the start time and end time 
        # is yet, for the moment set them both.
        opsdict[op_name] = { 'start_time': timestamp,
                            'end_time': timetstamp }
    else:
        # now evaluate the current timestamp against each start_time
        # and end_time value. Update as needed.
        if opsdict[op_name]['start_time'] > timestamp:
            opsdict[op_name]['start_time'] = timestamp
        if opsdict[op_name]['end_time'] < timestamp:
            opsdict[op_name]['end_time'] = timestamp
```

Now that we have a function to do the sorting, run through the CSV file reader and populate `ops`. When we're done, we can generate a new CSV file with the contents from our dictionary.

```
import csv

cr = csv.reader(open('/path/to/your/file.csv'))
cr_head = cr.next()    # throw away the first row

for row in cr:
    update_ops(ops, row)

# Now write a new csv file – csv.writer is your friend :)
with open('new_operation_times.csv', 'w') as newcsv:
    cw = csv.writer(newcsv)

    # first write your header. csv.writer accepts lists for each row.
    header = 'start_time,end_time,operation'.split(',')
    cw.writerow(header)

    # now write out your dict values. You may want them sorted, 
    # but how to do that has been answered elsewhere on SE.
    for opname, timesdict in ops.items():
        row = [ opname, timesdict['start_time'], timesdict['end_time'] ]
        cw.writerow(row)
```

And you're done! I've tried to make this as elaborate as possible so it's clear what's going on. You can probably collapse a lot of this into fewer, more clever steps (such as reading from one csv and writing it out directly). But if you follow the KISS principle, you'll have an easier time reading this later on, and learning from it again.

Comment: Thanks. Just a dumb question! Should I put each script in separate files?

Comment: I could manage it anyway. Now I'm getting an error: `update_ops(ops, row)
NameError: name 'ops' is not defined`

Comment: @Araz They should all be in the same file. Traditionally (and it's good practice), you should put both `import` lines together, at the top. 'ops' is defined in the upper section, with `ops = dict()`. It's called in the lower section, `for row in cr: update_ops(ops, row)`.

Comment: Thanks. I put both scripts in one file namely dict_pasrser.py. When I compile it I receive this error: `Traceback:
  File "dict_parser.py", line 31, in <module>
    update_ops(ops, row)
  File "dict_parser.py", line 9, in update_ops
    timestamp = dateutil.parser.parse(row[1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 1008, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 395, in parse
    raise ValueError("Unknown string format")
ValueError: Unknown string format`

Comment: Oh, silly me. Do you understand what the error is telling you? If you want to learn Python, follow the Traceback. The first error is where in the script it originated (and the line number in *your* script); the last error is telling you that the `dateutil.parser` module's method, `parse()`, is choking on its input.

Comment: I made a mistake, you see: a `csv.reader()` object is just an iterator, which goes line by line through a file, beginning at the *first line* of the csv file you feed it, and passes back a list for each row from there. The `update_ops` function runs the `dateutil.parser.parse()` method on the second item in the row, which ought to be a timestamp. But the *first* row of your file isn't like `Cassandra,2015-10-06T15:07:22.333662984Z,INSERT` – it's `name,time,Operations`.

Comment: So add an extra line to your script to *throw away* the first row. Since csv.reader() is just an iterator, as soon as you instantiate the object just insert a line like `cr_head = cr.next()` – and that should work. (i'll edit)

Comment: Thank you so much! Just a new error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dict_parser.py", line 43, in <module>
    for opname, timesdict in ops:
ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: Another mistake— common; I should've looped through ops.items() instead of ops alone.

Comment: I'm new to python and curious about "with" statement. My suspicion is when to use "with". Why your code snippet only use "with" with writer and not reader, does it only necessary to use with write mode?

Comment: @NattachaiSuteerapongpan `with` is entirely optional. It’s considered good form to use, and it has the benefit of providing a context for your file descriptor. However, it *closes* the file descriptor for you as soon as that context exits. I just didn’t use it here, mostly out of a concern of legibility and repairing the script on-the-fly from a mobile phone.