# When splitting commas, how to ignore commas in quotes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a .txt storage of an app. The app records the date in the form "time on month, date"
The data itself is word,how it is spelled,"time"(as shown above)

How do you split the data without splitting the time comma in the quotes?

this is the basic outline of the code

> ````
> >>file.read(filepath, r, encoding='utf-8')
> >>file.split(',')```
> ````

A sample of the data:

```
word,word,"1:03 on March 20,2020"
```

Does anyone have any ideas???
Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you post an example of the data you are trying to split?

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim I will edit to make some clearer data

Comment: It would be better to use a standard format like JSON, rather than doing ad hoc parsing like this. It takes care of all these issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Parse CSV Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296585/python-parse-csv-correctly)

Comment: @Barmar I made a mistake, I will edit it... 

Comment: @c2huc2hu it sort of does but I found my answer so I'm good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to split your string without splitting the date.

If you know your data should always be split three times (aka word, word and date) then use the maxsplit parameter in split

```
file.split(',', maxsplit = 2)
```

If you don't know how many splits you might need, I would reccomend making your own splitter funcition that checks whether the following and previous characters are numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex together with [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
pattern = '(?:".*?"|[^,])+'
```

The first part `".*?"` ensures that commas inside parentheses are skipped over. Since the whole group is repeated (`+`) it consumes up to the next comma. For example:

```
>>> re.findall(pattern, 'foo, "1, 2"abc, bar')
['foo', ' "1, 2"abc', ' bar']
```